# Expressão regular para match de conteudo entre ('<' ou "></") e ('>')

Tags: regex, xml

A partir de um texto em formato XML:

```
<shipto
 attr="xpto">
 <name>Nordmann</name>
 <address>Langgt 23</address>
 <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
</shipto>
```

Quero obter o match de:

1. `<shipto attr="xpto">`
2. `<name>Nordmann</name>`
3. `<address>Langgt 23</address>`
4. `<city>4000 Stavanger</city>`
5. `</shipto>`

Ou seja, o conteúdo compreendido entre `<` ou `></` e o char `>`.

Comment: Se possível, favor **[edit]** a pergunta e adicionar a linguagem que está usando, pois cada uma implementa regex de um jeito e o que funciona em uma pode não funcionar em outra (e coloque também o que já tentou). De qualquer forma, regex [nem sempre é a melhor ferramenta para mexer com XML/HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454), geralmente é melhor usar uma lib ou *parser* específico (que a maioria das linguagens possuem)

Comment: Além disso, se vc só quer "o que está entre `<` e `>`", então `<name>` e `</name>` não deveriam estar em *matches* separados? Ou tem regras diferentes para quando a tag tem outras tags dentro dela? Quando [edit] a pergunta, aproveite para esclarecer estes critérios...

Comment: obrigado, de fato o que eu precisava era de um parser: parseFromString("...", "text/xml");

Answer (score 0):

Usei um parser para gerar um objeto que permite trabalhar com o texto em formato XML:

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(this.mockXml, "text/xml");
```